# How to reverse rails generate <gemname>:install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When running this commandline, many files would be created
Is there any idea to reverse this? 
Go back to a former commit would be a solution, but that would also delete other files as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rails destroy <gemname>:install
```

Usually works.

Answer (score 0):

You uninstall gem will also work, or you can remove the gem name from the Gemfile and do a bundle install